# Chainable dynamic methods with __getattr__?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find a good pattern for resolving methods from a class variable in such a way that the methods can be chained. The two requirements are:

- Methods should be defined dynamically by a class variable.
- These dynamic methods should return `self` so that they can be chained.

For example, I want to be able to do something like this:

`color("WARNING").bold().yellow()`

The code below gets pretty close:

```
class color:
    colors = {
        "fg":{"black":"30","red": "31","green": "32","yellow": "33","blue": "34","magenta": "35","cyan": "36","white": "37"},
        "bg":{"black":"40","red": "41","green": "42","yellow": "43","blue": "44","magenta": "45","cyan": "46","white": "47"}
    }

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
        self.bright = "0"
        self.fore = "39"
        self.back = "49"

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name[-2:].lower() == "bg":
            self.back = self.colors['bg'][name[:-2]]
        elif name == "bold":
            self.bright = 1
        else:
            self.fore = self.colors['fg'][name]
        return self

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"\033[{self.bright};{self.fore};{self.back}m{self.text}\033[0m"
```

The problem is, this code sets the values *when the attribute is accessed*, as follows:

`color("WARNING").bold.yellow`

I feel like this is a "surprising" behavior, and one that should be avoided (read actions shouldn't change state). However, I'm not sure how to cleanly return a function prepopulated with the right values that will also return `self`. I've toyed with `functools.partial` and with using `__setattr__()` but I can't seem to get it right.

**Note:** This question is about correct patterns, *not* now to color text. The coloring of text is just a nice example.

Comment: You need to return a *callable* (e.g. a function), if that's the behaviour you want. That callable will then return self when invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Of course... I figured it out right after posting a question. Here's what I came up with:

```
from functools import partial

class color:
    colors = {
        "fg":{"black":"30","red": "31","green": "32","yellow": "33","blue": "34","magenta": "35","cyan": "36","white": "37"},
        "bg":{"black":"40","red": "41","green": "42","yellow": "43","blue": "44","magenta": "45","cyan": "46","white": "47"}
    }

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
        self.bright = "0"
        self.fore = "39"
        self.back = "49"

    def _set(self, name, val):
        # This method just calls __setattr__ to actually change the value,
        # but importantly, it returns self, so the methods can be chained.
        self.__setattr__(name, val)
        return self

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        # Return a partial function with the values already populated
        if name[-2:].lower() == "bg":
            return partial(self._set, "back", self.colors['bg'][name[:-2]])
        elif name == "bold":
            return partial(self._set, "bright", 1)
        return partial(self._set, "fore", self.colors['fg'][name])

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"\033[{self.bright};{self.fore};{self.back}m{self.text}\033[0m"
```